# List all public classes in a jar programatically

Tags: java

I have a jar file and I can list all classes in the jar.  The classes in the jar can be public, protected or package scope.  I wonder if it is possible to tell the scope and only list the public classes?

Comment: Sure it's possible. For example, you could load the classes with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html and use reflection to have the modifiers https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getModifiers(). Do you have some code already?

Comment: Classes only have _public_ and _package_ scopes.

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun classes can have protected scope: `public class Foo { protected static class Bar {} protected class Buzz {} }` What's wrong with the question is that they can also have private scope:  `public class Foo { private static class Bar {} private class Buzz {} }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so, and I can think of more than just one way how to do it, here are two:

- You can use a bytecode manipulation tool to read the `.class` files and get the modifier. The downside is that you need an extra library for that. The upside is that this way would be quite safe, as you don't need to load the class into the VM, just into memory, so no code is executed, and if the `.jar` classes depend on classes which are unavailable, this way would still work.
- You can use a `ClassLoader` with this `.jar` and load each of the classes, then inspect it using Reflection. The upside is that you do not need any third party libraries for this. The downside is that in order to inspect the classes, they need to be loaded by the `ClassLoader`, which means the code of these classes (static initializers) will be executed. If this is untrusted third party code, you will want to install a `SecurityManager` first to sandbox these classes. The other downside is that if these classes depend on other classes that are not available (for example by extending such unavailable classes), this approach would fail.
- You can use the `javap` tool to inspect the classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already listing the classes in the jar, you can use the Reflection interface to get the Class objects for those classes by name (String), and then use the Class interface to determine the properties of the class, for example isPublic, isFinal, or isStatic.

A quick search reveals:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/classes.html#modifiers